# Postgres: how to delete duplicate based on field in jsonb column

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, jsonb, node-postgres

I have a postgres table with a `created_at` and `data` column, where the data column is in jsonb format.

A row is considered duplicated if it has the same value for the `id` propery in the data column.

The table looks like this

```
  created_at   | data  
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  2018-03-20 | {"id": "abc", "name": "please"}
2  2018-01-10 | {"id": "sdf", "name": "john" }
3  2018-03-31 | {"id": "lkj", "name": "doe"  }
4  2018-02-30 | {"id": "dfg", "name": "apple"}
5  2018-05-24 | {"id": "dfg", "name": "seed" }
6  2018-03-27 | {"id": "23f", "name": "need" }
7  2018-11-14 | {"id": "abc", "name": "help" }
```

What is an efficient way to remove duplicates in this table? I do want to keep one instance behind

ie. if 5 entries have the same `id` I want to delete 4 and leave 1 of them in table

In this scenario I want to remove one of the entries with `id='abc'` and `id='dfg'`